# Does initializing an int have any side effects?

Tags: c, clang

I'm getting a clang warning from the following third party code in my project:

```
uLong x ;
int i;
int err;

err = unzlocal_getByte(pzlib_filefunc_def,filestream,&i); d
x = (uLong)i; // <- CLANG: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
```

So to get rid of this error I want to do change the initializing of i to:

```
int i = 0;
```

Will that cause any unintended consequences? I want to squash this warning without screwing anything up.

Comment: Is that lonely `d` on the right of the `unzlocal_getByte()` call intentional? That could be anything ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can change it to `int i = 0;`.

According to your code, initially `i` variable wasn't initialized, so it could contain arbitrary values, i.e. garbage.

I don't know, and even compiler also doesn't know, will function `unzlocal_getByte` actually change value of `i` variable, so it warns you about possible indeterminate state of `i` variable.

In any case, previously initializing `i` variable will not make situation worse.